# Parameter names and meaning of their values in an ENVI header file

Tags: envi

This is the header of an Envi file:

```
ENVI
description = {
PolSARpro File Imported to ENVI}
samples = 8407
lines   = 5569
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 4
interleave = bsq
sensor type = UAVSAR
byte order = 0
map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1, 1, -98.600943, 49.98488736, 0.000055560, 0.000055560, WGS-84}
band names = {
T11.bin }
```

[image]

I can understand the meaning of most of the parameters in this header but about the **map_info** field:

```
map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1, 1, -98.600943, 49.98488736, 0.000055560, 0.000055560, WGS-84}
```

**What are `1`,`1`,`0.000055560`,`0.000055560`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are your magic pixel easting, magic pixel northing, x pixel size, y pixel size.

see : http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVIHeaderFiles.html